# pip freeze lists numpy, but running the script says it is not found

Tags: python, python-venv

After I installed packages, then I run the program that doesn't run and report in the terminal below. Can you help me explain and treat it?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: can you find `numpy` installed in the `env3` environment

Comment: looks like you module is installed in a different then where you are trying to execute.
You may want to start Python first and see if numpy is installed in that python location

Comment: Many thanks, I try to install it again and it worked !!!

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.